# I am working in Yii2. I am trying to upload a file and try to save its path into the database but the path isn't saved

Tags: file, upload, yii2

I can successfully upload the file and try to save its path onto the database. But no path is saved. Here is a part of my code.

In my ItemsController:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Items();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

        $imageName = $model->item_name;
        $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');
        $model->file->saveAs('uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension);
        $model->item_pathname = 'uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension;


        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I can successfully save the file in the uploads folder and successfully change it to the item_name. But I can't get it to save the path in to my database image_pathname column. How can I do that? Thanks.

I've seen an example where you can directly input data into the database using `$models->sample_data = '';`. I don't know why mine doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save model after `item_pathname` change .

```
$model->item_pathname = ...;
$model->save();
```

Correct code would be

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {

    $imageName = $model->item_name;
    $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');
    $model->file->saveAs('uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension);
    $model->item_pathname = 'uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension;
    $model->save();
    ...
 }
```

First validate, then change the path and save.